# Returning updated item from dynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I am using the dynamoDB `ExpressionSpecBuilder` (Java) to create my update query for an item in the database. I would like the entire modified resource to be returned, without having to specify all attributes inidividually.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are forced to use `ExpressionSpecBuilder` I couldn't find any way.

However, there are other alternatives like `UpdateItemRequest` where you can set the `ReturnValues` property to `ALL_NEW` and get all attributes as a map:

```
UpdateItemRequest updateProgramCounterRequest = new UpdateItemRequest()
   .withTableName(...)
   .withUpdateExpression(...)
   .withReturnValues(ReturnValue.ALL_NEW);

UpdateItemResult updateItemResult = amazonDynamoDB.updateItem(updateItemRequest);
Map<String, AttributeValue> attributes = updateItemResult.getAttributes();
```

Then you can map them to your resource.

A higher level approach is using DynamoDBMapper. Depending on the type of update you need to do, you may also be able to achieve it using `save` method and modifying the `DynamoDBMapperConfig.SaveBehavior` property as described on javadoc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html#save-T-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBSaveExpression-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperConfig-